# Half circle using raphael

Tags: raphael

I'm very new to using raphael js library and I'm trying to figure it all out.  I'm trying to create a chart based on percentages where 100% would be a full circle. The circle part I have figured out, but how would I go about changing it to show a half-circle for 50% or a quarter of a circle for 25%?

Answer (score 12):

I recommend looking at the code behind [this](http://raphaeljs.com/pie.html) example on the Raphael home page. It should be easy enough to modify it to suit your needs.

This function in particular is what you're looking for

```
var rad = Math.PI / 180;
function sector(cx, cy, r, startAngle, endAngle, params) {
        var x1 = cx + r * Math.cos(-startAngle * rad),
        x2 = cx + r * Math.cos(-endAngle * rad),
        y1 = cy + r * Math.sin(-startAngle * rad),
        y2 = cy + r * Math.sin(-endAngle * rad);
    return paper.path(["M", cx, cy, "L", x1, y1, "A", r, r, 0, +(endAngle - startAngle > 180), 0, x2, y2, "z"]).attr(params);
}
```

so, a 50% slice would be

```
var fifty = sector(100,100,50,0,180,{"fill":"red"});
var twentyfive = sector(100,100,50,180,270,{"fill":"red"});
```

Of course, this is working with degrees - you may want to wrap it so that you can use percentages.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use path() and specify it using SVG's path syntax. Here is an example of creating a closed quarter-circle (upper left quadrant):

```
var arcPath = paper2.path("M200,200 v-150 a150,150 0 0,0 -150,150 z");
arcPath.attr("fill", "red");
```

See [this link](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/paths.html) for more on SVG Paths.